# How do you determine the server disconnection (case cut off cable ethernet)

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, python-3.x, mysql-python

I write code to determine the connection to remote server mysql. Here is my code:

```
import MySQLdb
def connect_remote():
   try:
       db = MySQLdb.connect("192.168.1.7", "root_a","","luan_van")
       return 1
   except MySQLdb.OperationalError, e:
       if e[0] == 2003:
           return 0
while 1:
   x = connect_remote()
   print x
```

If I "start or stop all service" wampserver in remote server (192.168.1.7), it worked well.

Now I assumed cut off cable ethernet connect server, the code is stop. How to identify this case?

I don't understand difference between disable mysql and cut off cable.

Comment: 'I don't understand difference between disable mysql and cut off cable': first returns an error 'immediately' from the remote stack, saying that nothing is listening on the port, second requires a long wait to ensure that no routes are available to the server, (one route might just be behind a satellite and two modem links).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only three cases you can distinguish are:

1. Server is on the network but actively rejecting connections on the MySQL port
2. Server is on the network but not responding at all to connection attempts on the MySQL port
3. Server is not responding to any network traffic

You cannot determine anything more detailed than these three cases, and distinguishing between 2 and 3 requires extra work, such as pinging the server to see if it responds at all.

To your specific question, there is no visible difference between the server being connected but unresponsive (i.e. OS crashed, case 3 above) and the cable being cut. You cannot tell the difference from a remote host.